# Custom translator - How can I train the machine to recognize the right translation solution (synonyms)?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I'm pretty new with Custom Translator and I'm working on a fashion-related EN_KO project.
There are many cases where a single English term has two possible translations into Korean. An example: if "fastening"is related to "bags, backpacks..." is 잠금 but if it's related to "clothes, shoes..." is 여밈.
I'd like to train the machine to recognize these differences. Could it be useful to upload a phrase dictionary? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of training a custom translation system is to teach it how to translate terms in context.

The best way to teach the system how to translate is training with parallel documents of full sentence prose: the same document in two languages. A translation memory extract in a TMX or XLIFF file is the best material, but many other document formats are suitable as well, as long as you have both languages. Have at least 10000 sentences in both languages, upload to http://customtranslator.ai, and build a custom system with it.
If you have documents in Korean that are representative of the terminology and style you want to achieve, without an English match, you can automatically translate those to English, and add to the training material as parallel documents. Be sure to not use the automatically translated documents in the other direction.

A phrase dictionary is of limited help, because it is unaware of context. It is useful only in bootstrapping your custom system or for very rare terms where you cannot find or create a sentence.